# Get text from a -textbox in other program- using hwnd

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, hwnd

hey, i have a window from a program, when i view it in UIspy i noticed that the RuntimeIds of the childs is like:

```
"window"      RuntimeId:        "42 1510446"  //parent
    "pane"    RuntimeId:        "42 394736"
    "image"   RuntimeId:        "42 1510446 2 0"
    "button"  RuntimeId:        "42 1510446 2 1"
    "text"    RuntimeId:        "42 1510446 2 2"
```

i need to get the content of "text" and i have a function that can do that but i need the hwnd.
does "text" have a hwnd (it should be 1510446 or something) ? or how can i access it?

Comment: UISpy uses the UIAutomation API to get its information. If you're not planning on using UIAutomation, you might want to use Spy++ instead, since it shows just HWNDs; can then use FindWindow() to get at the HWND.  What type of window/application is this that you're looking at?

Comment: thanks, i used UIAutomation. FindWindow never works with me. the type of window is win32 ( i think?)

Answer (score 0):

The `HWND` is assigned when the text window is created and so will differ everytime the window containing it is loaded.

You would need to:

1. Get the `HWND` of the containing window with `FindWindow(Ex)`
2. Using that as the parent `HWND` call `FindWindowEx` again specifying `TEXT` as the class name
3. Get the size of the actual text content with `SendMessage` / `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` & create a buffer
4. Fill that buffer with the value using  `SendMessage` / `WM_GETTEXT`

This assumes there is only one of that window class on the parent window and that `text` is an implementation of the stock `EDIT` class.

Comment: i have tried that, FindWindowEx returns only "pane"'s HWND (394736) and does not return any other result.